# Using (IN operator) OR condition in Where clause as AND condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Please look at following image, I have explained my requirements in the image.

[alt text http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/5668/shippment.png](http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/5668/shippment.png)

I can't use here `WHERE UsageTypeid IN(1,2,3,4)` because this will behave as an `OR` condition and fetch all records.

I just want those records, of first table, which are attached with **all 4 `ShipmentToID`** .

All others which are attached with 3 or less `ShipmentToID`s are not needed in result set.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `(EntityId, UsageTypeId)` is unique:

```
select s.PrimaryKeyField, s.ShipmentId from shipment s, item a
where s.PrimaryKeyField = a.EntityId and a.UsageTypeId in (1,2,3,4)
group by s.PrimaryKeyField, s.ShipmentId having count(*) = 4
```

otherwise, 4-way join for the 4 fields,

```
select distinct s.* from shipment s, item a,  item b, item c, item d where
s.PrimaryKeyField = a.EntityId = b.EntityId = c.EntityId = d.EntityId and
a.UsageTypeId = 1 and b.UsageTypeId = 2 and c.UsageTypeId = 3 and
d.UsageTypeId = 4
```

you'll want appropriate index on `(EntityId, UsageTypeId)` so it doesn't hang...

Answer (score 0):

This way is preferred to the multiple join against same table method, as you can simply modify the `IN` clause and the `COUNT` without needing to add or subtract more tables to the query when your list of IDs changes:

```
select EntityId, ShipmentId
from (
    select EntityId
    from (
        select EntityId
        from EntityUsage eu
        where UsageTypeId in (1,2,3,4)
        group by EntityId, UsageTypeId
    ) b
    group by EntityId
    having count(*) = 4
) a
inner join Shipment s on a.EntityId = s.EntityId
```

Answer (score 0):

If there will never be duplicates of the UsageTypeId-EntityId combo in the 2nd table, so you'll never see:

EntityUsageTypeId | EntityId | UsageTypeId
22685             | 4477     | 1
22687             | 4477     | 1

You can count matching EntityIds in that table.

`WHERE (count(*) in <tablename> WHERE EntityId = 4477) = 4`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @numShippingMethods int;
SELECT @numShippingMethods = COUNT(*) 
FROM shippedToTable;

SELECT tbl1.shipmentID, COUNT(UsageTypeId) as Usages
FROM tbl2 JOIN tbl1 ON tbl2.EntityId = tbl1.EntityId
GROUP BY tbl1.EntityID
HAVING COUNT(UsageTypeId) = @numShippingMethods
```